# ValueError: unsupported format character 'w' (0x77) at index 650

Tags: python, html, string, format

This is my first post in stackoverflow and hopefully I get an answer for my question.
I am trying to print on an html page a string sent from a python code, but when I return the string on the html page it shows me this error: "ValueError: unsupported format character 'w' (0x77) at index 650".
This is the python code:

```
def doctor_post(self, name, userID, password, telegramID):
    resp=open("response.html").read()
    new = {
        "name": name,
        "userID": userID,
        "password": password,
        "telegramID": telegramID,
        "patientsList": []
    }
    r = requests.post(self.Catalog+"/doctor", json=new)
    if r.status_code==200:
        out=resp % "Registered"
        return out
```

While the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Response</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>


<body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;"> Response</h1>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <!--The string specified in the python script after % will go instead of %s-->
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">%s</h3>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><input type="button" onclick="document.location.href='/';" value="Homepage"><br></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is good case to use some template engine, such as `jinja2` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally for something like this I rather use "replace":

- in the html, instead of `%s` I would use something like `___RESPONSE_VALUE___`
- in the python code `out = resp.replace("___RESPONSE_VALUE___", "Registered")`

For more complex items, I suggest you to check Jinja2 library, it is excellent for templating

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have a `% w` in your html file.

The "%" operator in python search for all `%` character in the string and do some replacement based on what's next.

To keep the "%s" as the placeholder value, replace all litteral `%` by `%%`.

As other mentioned, it's better to use something else than "%s" for the placeholder, like `___RESPONSE_VALUE___`, `{{ RESPONSE_VALUE }}` or using a templating system like `jinja`.

PS: Python also has the `str.format` function that's more advanced than "%" :

```py
print("Hello {} !".format("You"))
```